# codeigniter session does not returning the user agent or ip address or session id

Tags: codeigniter, session

I use this code in my controller:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('session');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

and this is the result :

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1524275027
    [identity] => admin
    [username] => admin
    [email] => admin
    [user_id] => 1
    [old_last_login] => 1524182225
    [last_check] => 1524274694
)
```

**I use codeigniter 3.1 with ion_Auth**

so how to get all data like user_agent , ip , ... ?

Comment: Why were you under the impression that the user agent or IP is stored in the session?

Answer (score 1):

Codigniter session library was re-written for version 3.0 and had some bug-fixes until the most recent version 3.1.8.

In earlier CI versions (2.x), the session data array had 4 items by default:

‘session_id’,
‘ip_address’,
‘user_agent’,
‘last_activity’

Now, in the new CI versions, you can still access these data like this (from the docs:)

> ```
>     session_id: session_id()
>     ip_address: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
>     user_agent: $this->input->user_agent() (unused by sessions)
>     last_activity: Depends on the storage, no straightforward way. Sorry!
> ```

see: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata
and: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-6-update-your-session-library-usage